# rendering two textures onto two separate objects via a single fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, lwjgl, fragment-shader

I have been trying to render two textures onto their own objects via a single fragment shader, but I keep having issues. Can someone please explain to me if this is possible, or how to do this.

my Fragment shader:

```
#version 460 core

in vec3 passColor;
in vec2 passTextureCoord;

out vec4 outTex;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main(){
    outTex = texture(tex, passTextureCoord);
    outTex = texture(tex2, passTextureCoord);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "single fragment shader". If you are rendering "two separate objects", then presumably that means you're issuing two separate draw calls, yes? So really, you're using the same fragment shader in two *separate* rendering operations. So why does your FS have two samplers, when it only ever uses one sampler *at a time*? It's like if you have a function that takes an `int` and adds 5 to it. If you want to call it from 20 different places in your code, the function doesn't take 20 integers. It just gets different parameters in each place it is used.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I apologize for the lack of information, but to answer your question, the textures belong to 2 different meshes.

Comment: @httpdigest I think it basically is, now that I think about it.

Comment: @rabbid76 I guess that does make sense